# Multiple forms in one view same action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have problem creating view with multiple forms with in same view where i have get action for data view and post action for data collection.

Here is my main view:

```html
@model Models.BuildingNewBuildingViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@if (TempData["Added"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        @TempData["Added"]
    </div>

}
@if (TempData["AddError"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        @TempData["AddError"]
    </div>

}
<h1>Svěřené budovy pro: @ViewBag.Name</h1>




<table class="table-bordered table-responsive table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id budovy</th>
            <th>Podlaží</th>
            <th>Použití</th>
            <th>Výměra</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Administrace</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NewBuildingViewModels.Count; i++)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "Form" }))
            {

                Html.RenderPartial("IndexPartial", Model.NewBuildingViewModels[i]);
            }

        }



    </tbody>


</table>
```

Here is form:

```html
@model Models.NewBuildingViewModel
    

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Building, Model.Building)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="@Url.Action("SetMarks", "Home", new {id = Model.Id})">@Model.Building</a></td>
        <td>
            @if (Model.Floor > 0)
            {
                @Model.Floor
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Floor)
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Floor, new {@Value = ""})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Floor)

            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (Model.Usage != null)
            {
                @Model.Usage
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Usage)

            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Usage)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Usage)
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (Model.Size > 0)
            {
                @Model.Size
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Size)

            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Size, new {@Value = ""})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Size)
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (Model.Date != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @Model.Date.Date
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Date)

            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Date)

            }
        </td>

        <td>
            @if (!Model.NewBuildingDataInDatabase)
            {
                <button type="submit">Odeslat</button>
            }
            else
            {
                if (Model.MarksInDatabase)
                {
                    <i class="fa fa-check checkIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("SetMarks", "Home", new {id =   Model.Id})">Zadat Hodnocení</a>
                }

            }

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And my problem is when i send non valid data to controller. Validation message shows for all forms. I want to see all forms but validation messages only for form which sended data.

Here is my action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(NewBuildingViewModel buildingNewBuildingViewModel)
    {
        BuildingForIcoCommand buildingForIcoCommand = new BuildingForIcoCommand();
        var buildingsForIco = buildingForIcoCommand.GetBuildingListForIco(AppContext);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = User.Identity.Name;
            ViewModelBuilder viewModelBuilder = new ViewModelBuilder();

            DaoBase<NewBuilding, int> daoBase = new DaoBase<NewBuilding, int>(AppContext.NhSession);
            daoBase.Save(viewModelBuilder.CreateNewBuilding(buildingNewBuildingViewModel));
            return View(buildingForIcoCommand.GetBuildingListForIco(AppContext));
        }

        return View("Index",buildingsForIco);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your form fields will have the name and id attributes because you are rendering them in a partial. This is why they are all flagged as invalid.

Any good solution will probably involve ajax.

One approach to revolving this would be to use a single edit form. Each rendered item would have an edit button, clicking this button would populate the form with the item's data via javascript. This could be a modal or similar. This approach works well with jQuery / unobtrusive validation.

Another approach would be to return a custom response from your controller eg status 400 and the invalid fields derived from the model state. You can then show a suitable error message in the right field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to set specific name and id but then is nothing marked as invalid. I wonder if I should add the same specific name to validationmessagefor? Or what is best way to do multiple forms in one view to same action and their validation ?